# Firefox Developer Tools Network export to pcap

Tags: firefox, pcap, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way to export the network data to say a pcap, from the Firefox Developer Tools Network tab? I haven't seen an option, but this would be really useful in sending issues to others.

Comment: What do you want to export that would be easier to analyze in Wireshark than reading as JSON/file in the Network tab? (I am not aware of any way of doing this in Firefox/Chrome dev tools).

Comment: Say I encounter an error, but the other person can't recreate it. I could dump the pcap and send it to them. Instead of having to copy and paste each of the important packets...